# Database design: Products issue

Tags: mysql

I have a website which is based on delivering from restaurants.
The restaurants food menus can have multiple add-ons/additions, for example a Burger and Fries/Chips meal, can come in small, medium and large, and the burger could be chicken or veggie. 
The admin are allowed to add unlimited add-ons, my issue is i cannot work out how i would design my database to hold all this information.

These are my tables:

**Product Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
`Product_Id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Resturant_ID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
`Product_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Product_Desc` text NOT NULL,
`Product_Price` decimal(65,0) NOT NULL,
`Add_On_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Product_Id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Add on table**

```
 CREATE TABLE `Add_On` (
 `Add_On_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Add_On_Name` text NOT NULL,
 `Add_On_Price` mediumint(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Add_On_ID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In the products table do i just add many add_on_id rows. or do i use my dynamic add on button which add's the unlimited add-ons to insert a row into the products and add-ons table?

Comment: Perhaps you could do the add ons as a JSON array/object that's stored inside one column?

Comment: You could do the above (JSON object in the database), or consider a table Product_Addons that links the chosen base product to the selected add-on(s) instead of the Add_On_ID field in your schema.

Comment: @AndyHolmes so there is no need to store the information inside a database? i can just store the information into lets say for a example a session instead

Comment: @ChrisFlynn okay thank you, i will try that

Comment: DECIMAL(65,0) ??? What are you selling? Solar systems? Anyway, this question is OT for SO. Maybe try those suckers over in the dba forum.

Comment: @JJ123 If you dont store this info into a database it is not going to be there for anybody except the admin, and then only until he logs off

Comment: Come to that, I think you should start with a search for a MYSQL Database Design tutorial. Many Many mistakes have been made already and you are only just starting. You are going to be in a real mess in a few more days. Sorry, but sometimes the truth hurts

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats fine i rather know from the start.

Comment: @JJ123 No I meant store all the options as one array/object inside a column. I've done it for a leopard gecko genetics calculator I'm building, saves using a bunch of columns